# Is there a Firefox addon to test JavaScript in browser?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

What I'm looking to do is not write JavaScript in the source of the website.  But use an addon/extension to type JavaScript in a browser console and see the results in the browser.  Kind of like JSFiddle, but for your own sites.

Comment: how about the developed console?

Comment: Are you on the "Console" tab in the developer tools? If so, you type things in at the very bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the developer tools in Firefox (available in essentially all browsers at this point).

In Firefox, the shortcut to open them is CTRL+SHIFT+K.  Then go to the Console tab, and you can type JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: How do you put input and run in this example?  I have no input here.

Comment: There's an input on the bottom that runs the full length of the window.  Type your JavaScript in there and hit Enter.

Comment: There it is!  It's so micro/small it's barely noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

I have found 3 ways to do it.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts is the official source.

#### Answer #1

@[Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895604/mike) gave a good answer with **CTRL-SHIFT-K** which brings up a console.  The console permits a one line command to be run.  (It's so small it's barely noticeable.)

#### Answer #2 (winner)

This is part of the **Firebug** addon. @[apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710446/apsillers) had originally commented **CTRL-SHIFT-C** from there you click **Console** and then a tiny side arrow on the right opens up a side entry for JavaScript with a **run command**.  This is exactly like **JSFiddle** so [apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/710446/apsillers) has given the correct answer which he has then removed.

#### Answer #3 (awesome)

And one I discovered from the Mozilla documentation which is AWESOME is **SHIFT-F4**.  This opens a **SMART JavaScript editor**, known as the **JavaScript Scratchpad**, window with a **run button**, **auto-complete** features, and allows you to **save your work**.